# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPN5j.png) I encountered an error while trying to install mysql2 (0.5.5), which is preventing Bundler from proceeding with the installation. I am using a Mac with OS Ventura (13.3.1). Even though I have already installed mysql and mysql-client through brew, I am still facing this issue. I have included snippets of the error below. Despite my attempts, the problem persists.

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
-----
Cannot find library dir(s) /opt/homebrew/bin/openssl/lib
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --with-openssl-dir
        --with-openssl-include
        --without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
        --with-openssl-lib
        --without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/mysql2-0.5.5 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:102:in `run'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:28:in `build'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:170:in `build_extension'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:204:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `each'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in
`install'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in
`do_install'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in
process_queue'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/gems/bundler-2.4.8/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2
levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

mkmf.log file

```
have_func: checking for rb_absint_size()... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_size; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_singlebit_p; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_gc_mark_movable; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
conftest.c:14:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_wait_for_single_fd'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: extern void rb_wait_for_single_fd();
15: int t(void) { rb_wait_for_single_fd(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
conftest.c:16:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_enc_interned_str'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_enc_interned_str; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <ruby.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_enc_interned_str; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/arm64-darwin22 -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.1/lib -L. -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.3.2  -lpthread  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <ruby.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: extern void rb_enc_interned_str();
17: int t(void) { rb_enc_interned_str(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: That's not full stacktrace. You gave 0 helpful information with that snippet

Comment: @uday update the error list

Comment: what did you find in /Users/vdwivedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1@patient_cloud_settings/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

Comment: @dbugger I have added the logs now

Comment: Looks like OpenSSL is not installed , or at least not installed where ruby expects it

Comment: @dbugger , after adding OpenSSL correct path in bash_profile . OpenSSL is not listed issue is gone , but main issue still remains i have udpated the log file attached